# Remove subdirectory from URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, split, substring, subdirectory

I would like to remove the "sg" subdirectory from the URL (https://testing.com/sg/features/), resulting in (https://testing.com/features/).

Let's say if my window.location.href is https://testing.com/sg/features/, I need to edit and remove "sg" subdirectory from it, and then put it into a new location without hardcoding it. Meaning that it will dynamically get the URL and then go to the location without "sg" (https://testing.com/features/).

```
var url = 'https://testing.com/sg/features/';

var x = url.split('/');

console.log(x[3]); //result: sg
```

I was only able to get the sg out from the URL but am not sure how do I remove it.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the best way is to split by '/', look for a section which exactly is the string you want to remove and reassemble the new string while ignoring the matches. This code removes every /sg/ in the string

```js
let thisLocation = "https://testing.com/sg/features/";
        
let splitLoc = thisLocation.split('/');
let newLocation = "";
        
for (let i = 0; i < splitLoc.length; i++){
    if (splitLoc[i] !== "sg")
        newLocation += splitLoc[i] + '/';
}
        
newLocation = newLocation.substring(0, newLocation.length - 1);
```

You could also do a global .replace while looking for '/sg/'. Your choice

Comment: Great answer, works pretty good. But if i were to make it another way around, from (https://testing.com/features) to (https://testing.com/sg/features), how would you propose that to be done? Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: `var url=window.location.href.replace("testing.com/", "testing.com/sg/");location = url;`
I did it like this but I'm not sure if this is a good solution although it gets the job done.

Comment: @HaydenNg If you have the first part of the URL that's always the same, this solution works fine.

Otherwise, you could remove the HTTP:// | https:// part from the URL. After that, look for the next / and insert "sg/" in that position of the string.

Comment: I'm afraid that the solution is a bit limited. It turns out that when I have more than one country, for example I switch in a dropdown, from (https://testing.com/ie/features/) to (https://testing.com/sg/features). The resulting URL becomes (https://testing.com/sg/ie/features). The replacing codes are like this : `var url = window.location.href.replace("testing.com/", "testing.com/ie/");` Adding if else can fix this but I don't want to use that way to avoid long codes. Looking for a more dynamic way

Comment: So if there is a way to target directly the /sg/ || /ie/ that would help solve the problem. Thanks 

Comment: Sorry the resulting URL is : (testing.com/ie/sg/features/)

Comment: I guess I better open a new thread for this. Thanks a lot mate. If you like to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433529/changing-country-code-subdirectory-from-url