# Changing country code subdirectory from URL

Tags: javascript, substring, href, subdirectory, country-codes

I need to change the country code in the URL when I select the country from the dropdown.

Currently I only have 3 countries in the dropdown, but when I switch from SG (testing.com/sg/features) to IE, the resulting URL becomes (testing.com/ie/sg/features). It works fine when I switch from IE(testing.com/ie/features) to SG(testing.com/sg/features) tho.

```
<form name="form1">
    <select class="region regionTopBar" onchange="formChanged(this);" name="country" size="1" style="font-family: inherit; padding: 5px; border:0px; outline:0px;">
        <option value="/">International</option>
        <option value="sg/">Singapore</option>
        <option value="ie/">Ireland</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
function formChanged(form) {
  var formCountryCode = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
  var formCountryName = form.options[form.selectedIndex].text;
        if (formCountryCode !== null) {
          if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.country = formCountryCode ;
            localStorage.currentSite = formCountryName ;
          }
        if(formCountryCode == "sg/"){
            var url = window.location.href.replace("testing.com/", "testing.com/sg/");
            location = url;
        }
        else if(formCountryCode == "ie/"){
            var url = window.location.href.replace("testing.com/", "testing.com/ie/");
            location = url;
        }

//remove country code from URL when International is selected
          else {
                var thisLocation = window.location.href;
        
                var splitLoc = thisLocation.split('/');
                var newLocation = "";

                for (let i = 0; i < splitLoc.length; i++){
                    if (splitLoc[i] !== "sg" && splitLoc[i] !== "ie")
                        newLocation += splitLoc[i] + '/';
                }

                newLocation = newLocation.substring(0, newLocation.length - 1);
                location = newLocation ;
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Adding if else like this can fix the issue but as the number of countries increase, it is going to be a mess.

```
else if(formCountryCode == "ie/"  && window.location.href.indexOf("sg/") < 1){
    var url = window.location.href.replace("testing.com/", "testing.com/ie/");
    location = url;
}
else if(formCountryCode == "ie/" && window.location.href.indexOf("sg/") > 0){
    var url = window.location.href.replace("testing.com/sg/", "testing.com/ie/");
    location = url;
}
```

So I am looking for a dynamic way to achieve this.

Comment: is testing.com your host name i.e. https://testing.com ?

Comment: nope but it is just an example of a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can leave out the domain and do this for all country codes.

```js
window.location.href = "/" + formCountryCode
```

as the domain remains unchanged.

if there is a pathname, then you can do

```js
window.location.href = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/.+?\//, "/" + formCountryCode + "/")
```

if the pathname is / then we can do this

```js
const path = window.location.pathname;

window.location.href = path === "/" ?
    "/" + formCountryCode :
    path.replace(/\/.+?\//, "/" + formCountryCode + "/");
```

Comment: But this only goes to the homepage (testing.com/sg/) instead of (testing.com/sg/features).

Comment: updated my answer to handle your use case

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about this way but it works pretty good. 
Thanks for your answer mate. Have a good day :)

Comment: Oh there is a bug. When you are at testing.com and wants to go to testing.com/sg/, it doesn't work. How do you cater for this as well?